# Pushing new view controller from UITableView on a Tab Bar application

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have an app with two bar in it.
one of the tab .xib includes `UITableView`, when the user select one of the cells, I want to show another `UIViewcontroller` (.xib file) that includes information about the his selection.

now, I've tried this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
*)indexPath { 
NextViewController *nextController = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];   
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];     [nextController changeProductText:[arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
}
```

and nothing happened, the console is showing no errors at all.

what seems to be the problem?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happened, because your self.navigationController returns nil.
For proper usage of Navigation controller, you must have at least one. For the case of TabBar application, for each tab you must associate not the UIViewController subclass, but UIViewController subclass nested in UINavigationController. That's easily done both in the .xib or in code. Just google for some tutorials.